# Doctrine 2 cli - Command Line Tool - Unexpected character in input - Generate entities

Tags: codeigniter, command-line, doctrine-orm, command-line-interface

I am having a problem with running commands via cli `doctrine-cli.php` file. I am using Doctrine 2 and Codeigniter 2. I would like to generate entities via Command Line Tool, but without success. Page is hosted by [Hostgator](http://www.hostgator.com). On this server is installed by default PHP version 5.2, but you can use PHP version 5.3 by adding some commands to .htaccess file located in root.

In the Command Line Tool I get this error:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/tig3rb0y/public_html/naselsi/application/doctrine-cli.php on line 10

Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/tig3rb0y/public_html/naselsi/application/doctrine-cli.php on line 10

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/tig3rb0y/public_html/naselsi/application/doctrine-cli.php on line 10
```

If I run a file with PHP version via url, I get PHP version 5.3, but if I run the same file via Command Line Tool, I get php version 5.2. Why is that so?

Is there any solution for that?

Regards, Mario

Comment: That is because PHP-CLI and PHP under Apache2 are completely different processes. I think the best is to contact your hosting provider if they can somehow enable 5.3.x in the command line.

Comment: @KeesSchepers Thank you for your reply. I already contacted them and they can not enable PHP 5.3.x.. I don't know why :( So, there is no other solutions for that?

Comment: unfortunately there isn't since Doctrine needs version 5.3.x in order to work. I don't think there aren't many other options cause you properly don't have SSH access to your host with the right privileges.

Comment: I have SSH access to my host.. As I see, I'll have to write these models alone, at least until they take PHP version 5.3.x as the default version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. As already @KeesSchepers said, there was a problem that in command line there was default 5.2.17 PHP version. I solved that simply, I just added prefix `/opt/php53/bin/php` to all doctrine2 commands, example:

`/opt/php53/bin/php doctrine-cli.php orm:...`

Thank you guys!